# Firemonkey / Из своего приложения запустить скачивание файла

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey

Как я могу использовать диспетчер загрузки Android, чтобы скачать нужный?
[Здесь написано как](http://www.ohandroid.com/50451.html), но не пойму как на delphi xe это реализовать.

```cpp
public class DLManager {

  @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
  public static void useDownloadManager(String url, String name, Context c) 
  { 
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)c.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); 
    DownloadManager.Request dlrequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url)); 
    dlrequest.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
      .setTitle("Title")
      .setDescription("Downloading in Progress..")
      .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Directory_name", name + ".jpg")
      .allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    dm.enqueue(dlrequest); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ни разу не работал с `FMX`, но [может это подойдет](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMX.Android_Download_Service_Sample)? Если что - сам [код проекта находится здесь](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Tokyo/Object%20Pascal/Multi-Device%20Samples/Device%20Sensors%20and%20Services/DownloadServiceDemo/).

Comment: Несовсем то. Я вот как раз понять не могу как это реализовывается. Может нужно качать своей программой, а в статус бар выводить уведомление (значек) закачки?!

Comment: Так, Вам ведь необходимо загрузить файл? Верно? Пример по ссылке выше как раз это и делает. Цитата из описания: *When the image file is downloaded to the device, a notification is presented.* Т.е. загружает картинку и отображает уведомление. Вы пробовали скомпилировать пример?

Comment: Да, компилируется проект DownloadImage который и инсталируется на сматрфон. При нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит. Не качается ничего. А почему там групповой проект?

Comment: Совсем ничего? Раз так, да еще и 3 дня прошло, а ответа нет, то, возможно, следует попробовать задать Ваш вопрос на [англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi). Почему групповой проект - я не знаю. Я никогда не работал с мобильной разработкой. Просто поискал у них на сайте - пример есть. Подумал, что подойдет.